# How to export into word format using Reporting Services (SSRS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Using Reporting services in SQL Server 2005 in asp.net with c#, how can we export reports in word document?

Thanks In Advance.!!

Comment: Are you calling the report via SSRS API from your code? The easiest approach would be to export teh report to HTML using standard API and then use Word API to save it as word doc.

Answer (score 1):

in ssrs 2008 and in report viewer control you can export your report to word format directly.